# Something goes wrong when using HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to covert a string into a number array, so I defined a hash map to do the job. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DES {

static HashMap<String, Integer> numMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private static void init(){
    numMap.put("a", 0);
    numMap.put("b", 1);
    numMap.put("c", 2);
    numMap.put("d", 3);
    numMap.put("e", 4);
    numMap.put("f", 5);
    numMap.put("g", 6);
    numMap.put("h", 7);
    numMap.put("i", 8);
    numMap.put("j", 9);
    numMap.put("k", 10);
    numMap.put("l", 11);
    numMap.put("m", 12);
    numMap.put("n", 13);
    numMap.put("o", 14);
    numMap.put("p", 15);
    numMap.put("q", 16);
    numMap.put("r", 17);
    numMap.put("s", 18);
    numMap.put("t", 29);
    numMap.put("u", 20);
    numMap.put("v", 21);
    numMap.put("w", 22);
    numMap.put("x", 23);
    numMap.put("y", 24);
    numMap.put("z", 25);
    numMap.put(" ", 26);
    numMap.put(".", 27);
    numMap.put(",", 28);
    numMap.put("?", 29);
    numMap.put("(", 30);
    numMap.put(")", 31);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    init();

    String plaintext = "how do you like computer science";
    String[] splittext=plaintext.split("");
    int[] numtext=new int[splittext.length];
    for(int i=0;i<splittext.length;i++)
    {
        numtext[i]=numMap.get(splittext[i]);
        System.out.println(numtext[i]);
    }
}


}
```

I got a 'nullpointerexception' when running, but I guess the hash map is ok, since I tried something like

```
 numtext[i]=numMap.get("z");
```

And it works fine. So maybe there is some issues with my splittext array?

Comment: Maybe you should point out where exactly the `NullPointerException` is happening. My guess is that you can't split on an empty string...

Comment: I guess split on an empty string would split the 'plaintext' string letter by letter, and so it did. I did an iteration through the array 'splittext', and yes, each element is a single letter. And of course, the exception happens on "numtext[i]=numMap.get(splittext[i]);"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrays.toString(splittext)`:

```
[, h, o, w,  , d, o,  , y, o, u,  , l, i, k, e,  , c, o, m, p, u, t, e, r,  , s, c, i, e, n, c, e, ]
```

The first element of `splittext` is the empty string, which has no mapping in your `HashMap` and hence `NullPointerException` on `get()`.

You can fix this by skipping the first element of `splittext`. `String#split()` has a way to avoid trailing whitespace, but not leading whitespace, so I don't think you can do it any other way.

A better solution is just to use `String#toCharArray()` which is better than splitting on an empty string :)

Comment: Exactly! Skipping the first element fixes it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`String[] splittext = plaintext.split("");` creates an array with empty strings

```
[, h, o, w,  , d, o,  , y, o, u,  , l, i, k, e,  , c, o, m, p, u, t, e, r,  , s, c, i, e, n, c, e]
```

and numMap.get(""); returns null. You can add an entry with key="" to the map to fix the problem

```
    numMap.put("", 32);
```

Comment: Yes, the first element, which is an empty string causes the problem.

Comment: You sure you didn't just copy from my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just splitting the string on every character, I would consider just storing the chars in the map, use `plaintext.toCharArray()`, and then loop through the result array, looking up each char in your map

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split the String using an entry string pattern ("") as a result the String does not get split, and you get NullPointerException as you are trying to access the split String (which does not exist). Try splitting the String using ("\s") which will split the string on spaces.

Hope this helps.